# Storing data using jquerymobile and phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I currently creating web apps that can save user setting by using jquerymobile and phonegap. But I dont know is it possible to save user setting that will not reset after closing apps?

Thank you and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LocalStorage, right? I think IOS & Android both support it.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: Will its variable content get deleted after closing the apps?

Comment: No, it does not. Look at the definition of LocalStorage in the link I sent you